# ListView only printing first value from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I've tried searching other questions, and most of them are to do with having the listview inside a scrollview, but I have no scrollview so it wasn't of much help. I'm sure it's something small I'm missing but I can't seem to pinpoint it. The below is supposed to print out the 3 animalNames to the listview, but is only printing the first.

```
JSONArray mainNode = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset()); // call the connection to json
        ArrayList<String> animalsArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(mainNode != null) //puts the values into an array
        {
            for(int i=0;i<mainNode.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject eachObject = mainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                animalsArray.add(eachObject.getString("animalName"));
            }

            //prints array to check
            for(String stuff : animalsArray)
            {
                Log.i("name", stuff);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animalsArray);
            animalsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.animalList);
            animalsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
```

This prints out the 3 values within my JSON to logcat, so I'm sure it's getting the values, I'm just unsure as to why it's only printing the first position into the list.

In case it's of any use, my current layout is below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/animalList"/>
```

Any ideas as to why it's only printing the first would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Showing only one value in `Log.i("name", stuff);` line?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK _This prints out the 3 values within my JSON to logcat._ He mentioned it.

Comment: Nope, that's printing out all 3, hence why I know the values are there which made me even more confused!

Comment: @Navvy the what is this **the below is supposed to print out the 3 animalNames to the listview, but is only printing the first.** supposed to mean if its printing all 3

Comment: @Navvy Have you tried placing the _ListView_ in a _RelativeLayout_?

Comment: you have the height equal to the height of the list item in the list. so you do not see the other two

Comment: `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"`   doesn't look good to me. What about a more simple `wrap_content`?

Comment: @Navvy try having LinearLayout height to wrap_content also read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listPreferredItemHeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the height of your linear layout correspond to the height of one listView item :

> android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

Set the height with other value (like match_parent if you want full screen height)